# Authorize and AllowAnonymous attribute MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've the following class

```
[Authorize]
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult GetUsersList()
    {
    }
}
```

Config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name=".AppUser" timeout="2000"/>
</authentication>
```

Though I've added AllowAnonymous for GetUsersList() Action, it still redirects to Login page. The GetUsersList is called through ajax

I do not have any custom authorization.

Comment: Check to make sure you are using the correct namespace. both attributes exist in Web API as well.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks. But both refers to System.Web.MVC

Comment: Is your page where you return the GetUsersList is under AllowAnonymous? If this is under partial view, the main view should be under AllowAnonymous as well.

Comment: @WillyDavidJr   The Layout page for the given view is partial view. I mean the master page is partial